# Problem using Python's poplib to check email

Tags: python, email, stat, poplib

When I use Python's poplib stat() method to check how many emails there are, it returns 0 even though there are emails in the server.  Does anyone know why this happens?

I can connect to the server with my email address and password, but I can't see any emails.

Here's my code:

```py
import poplib

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL("pop.gmail.com")

pop_conn.user("myemail@gmail.com")

pop_conn.pass_("mypassword")

print('Messages: %s. Size: %s' % pop_conn.stat())

pop_conn.quit()
```

returns:
`Messages: 0. Size: 0`

Comment: Have you verified that there are actually messages present? Does `pop_conn.list()` return results that are different from what `.stat` provides?

Comment: It's 2021. Whatever are you doing using POP3 instead of the now decades old IMAP protocol?

Comment: pop_conn.list() returns an empty list, but there are messages present if I log into gmail on a browser.  Do they not show up because they've been read?

Comment: I didn't know about IMAP, I'll research that.  Thank you.

Comment: Try to delete the line "pop_conn.quit()", send new messages and run the code. It worked for me.